# Site disappears in Safari, why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, cross-browser

[If you take a look at this site](http://cabiweb.inforce.dk)

the site is displayed fine in IE, FF, Chrome, however, if you look at it with Safari, it hides the site? Can't quite seem to figure out what's tricking this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the z-index of `<div id="bg-box"></div>` to negative value;Now it is `z-index: 1`; Turned it to `z-index: -1`.I think it may work.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't in my Safari (up-to-date, SL)

Answer (score 0):

It does show for a split second. All the elements in your divs are still there. Play around with your sizing and positioning. I have a good feeling that is messing it up.

Answer (score 0):

your `bg-box` class has a z-index of 1. Your other classes have no z-index. In Safari no z-index is less than a z-index of 1 (sometimes). Set your other top level divs to have a z-index of 2 and it all looks fine.